# Unable to call Webservice (asmx) from Windows Mobile 6.5 on IIS

Tags: web-services, iis, windows-mobile-6.5, bad-request

My asmx Service is hosted on IIS. On making request from windows mobile 6.5 browser it returns HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST. While I run this service on local environment it works fine ....
Kindly reply as soon as possible ...
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator issue !! when i installed my app in mobile and called web service from IIS .. it works fine.

--- > Emulator's unable to call web service installed on IIS

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can elaborate more on the issue. Still I would like to give you few check lists.

1) To enable web service access outside localhost add the following to web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet"/>
                <add name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2) If you do not have a public IP then mobile and your IIS host should be on the same LAN.

3) Also enable sharing of data via USB in activesync. By doing this your mobile will share the internet from the host

Try these and let me know if it is working.